# How to create and print a Dictionary that has keys as the names in list and their values as number of times the name appears on the list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of names:

```
list = ['Ginger', 'Willow', 'Scout', 'Roscoe', 'Bear', 'Kobe', 'Baxter', 'Zara', 'Fiona', 'Milo', 'Oakley', 'Dakota', 'Prince', 'Bruno', 'Panda', 'Dexter', 'Ziggy', 'Roscoe', 'Lucy', 'Boomer', 'Fiona', 'Ella', 'Emma', 'Oakley']
```

Using this list, I've created the following dictionary:

```
listA = {"G": "Ginger", "W": "Willow", "S": "Scout", "R": ["Roscoe", "Roscoe"], "B": ["Bear", "Baxter", "Bruno", "Boomer"], "K": "Kobe", "Z": ["Zara", "Ziggy"], "F": ["Fiona", "Fiona"], "M": "Milo", "O": ["Oakley", "Oakley"], "D": ["Dakota", "Dexter"], "P": ["Prince", "Panda"], "L": "Lucy", "E": ["Ella", "Emma"]}
```

Printing the keys from the dictionary:

```
for key in listA.keys():
    print(key)
```

I get:

```
G
W
S
R
B
K
Z
F
M
O
D
P
L
E
```

How can I get the number of times that each name appears in the list?

Comment: What's the desired outcome? What is the problem when trying to derive it?

Comment: @enke I was expecting the below outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `listA`; `collections.Counter` does exactly what you're looking for.

```py
import collections
data = ['Ginger', 'Willow', 'Scout', 'Roscoe', 'Bear', 'Kobe', 'Baxter', 'Zara', 'Fiona', 'Milo', 'Oakley', 'Dakota', 'Prince', 'Bruno', 'Panda', 'Dexter', 'Ziggy', 'Roscoe', 'Lucy', 'Boomer', 'Fiona', 'Ella', 'Emma', 'Oakley']
counter = collections.Counter(data)

print(counter) # Prints counter object.
counter_as_dict = dict(counter) # Can be transformed into a dictionary using dict().
print(counter_as_dict.keys()) # Prints names in dictionary.
```

Comment: Thank you. It gave me this output: Counter({'Roscoe': 2, 'Fiona': 2, 'Oakley': 2, 'Ginger': 1, 'Willow': 1, 'Scout': 1, 'Bear': 1, 'Kobe': 1, 'Baxter': 1, 'Zara': 1, 'Milo': 1, 'Dakota': 1, 'Prince': 1, 'Bruno': 1, 'Panda': 1, 'Dexter': 1, 'Ziggy': 1, 'Lucy': 1, 'Boomer': 1, 'Ella': 1, 'Emma': 1})

Comment: Yes. You can index it using brackets. If you want a dictionary specifically, you can do `dict(counter)`. If you're looking to fix something else about this solution, please specify that in a comment below.

Comment: How can I use dict(counter)? If I want to print only the keys as the names in list?

Comment: Edited into original answer.